How to store handle messages in chat server
I am designing a chat server in C that uses a thread-pool + event polling. When a read event is detected, a thread processes that message, but I'm not sure how to store it.
Right now I have a thread-safe hash map I designed that contains user structs that contain fields for a message queue of incoming messages to that user. So when a write event is detected, a thread will query the hash map (which maps usernames to user structs), dequeue all messages in that user's message queue and use send() to write to that user's socket. This approach is fine for private messaging, but if 10 people are in a group, then this poses a problem as my hash map has a read-write lock on every bucket, so each time someone sends a group message I'd have to lock/unlock 10 times for the bucket, and then again for the message queues. I was wondering if there is a better way to fix this design problem?

How about a structure with a size and a flexible array member. Allocate the structure and its data dynamically, and store the pointer to it.

Why hash map? Do you need to store and search the message log?

"my hash map has a read-write lock on every bucket", can you try to take lock when you are performing a read operation (query, search) or write operation (insert, delete), instead of putting lock on buckets?

I have a hash map because I need to be able to map usernames to socket descriptors. The reason why I had read-write locks on every bucket was to increase concurrency, a singular lock would be a bottleneck. Is there a safe way to iterate through the hash map like how Java does in ConcurrentHashMap?

If you read the API docs for Java's ConcurrentHashMap, especially the class-level docs, then you will get some clues about how it achieves its concurrency and performance characteristics, as well as what some of the costs are.  The underlying hash table and all the class's methods are carefully designed to make it work. The same can be done in C, of course, but it's not a matter merely of a special way to manipulate the hash table you already have.

Possibly you will find something useful with the search terms "C lock free queue".
